# Saving a screen shot in ./ directory testcafe

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, screenshot, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am running testcafe with the options --screenshots --screenshots-on-fails
what I want it to do is save a screen shot in my current working directory but instead, it saves it in screenshots/${DATE}_${TIME}/....... is there a way to specify a file to put the screen shot in like

```
--screenshots -n "./foo.png" --screenshots-on-fails
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestCafe now supports screenshot path patterns.

In TestCafe v1.5.0 and newer, use the [pathPattern](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/command-line-interface.html#pathpattern) parameter.